# Linux Command Line Using gedit

Tags: linux, command-line

If I'm trying to access a file using gedit, how can I reach this file if there are spaces in the name?  Right now typing the file name creates separate files, one for each word in the name

Comment: Have you tried using tab complete? Just hit the tab key after typing part of the filename

Answer (score 4):

Surround the filename with double-quote (`"`) characters.  For example:

```
gedit "my resume"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either surround it with quotes as Fran suggested or use a backslash to escape spaces in filenames and directories:

```
$ gedit /path\ to/text\ file.txt
# opens /path to/text file.txt
```